# macos ssh server disconnects

Tags: macos, ssh

I am using an ubuntu client to connect to a macos.

Macos has an internal ssh server that disconnect my client when the screen goes to login screen.

How to keep the server working?

Comment: Which macOS version is used? Does this happen every time when the login screen appears or just first time after reboot?

Comment: It's 10.15.4. When the screen blacks out, ssh get unresponsive until disconnection

Comment: Most likely this is caused by the sleep/hibernate mode. You have to disable both if you want to run a background service like ssh.